# T32 script usage

Tags: trace32

Can anyone help me on this script?
What did the function do?
Thanks!

========================================================

&AAA=0

if (string.scan(string.lwr("&parameters"),"AAA",0)!=-1)

(
  &AAA=1
)

========================================================

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I guess your code looks like this:

```
&AAA=0
if (string.scan(string.lwr("&parameters"),"AAA",0)!=-1)
(
  &AAA=1
)
```

Note: The round brackets for opening and closing a block in a PRACTICE script must be placed in separate lines.

About the meaning: Your script has two "variables" (aka. "macro"): `&parameters` and `&AAA`.

- In the first line you initialize `&AAA` with 0.
- In the second line you use string.lwr() to get the content of the variable `&parameters` converted to lower-case.
- Then you search in this lower-case string for a string "AAA" (which is ironically upper case) beginning from the first letter (with string.scan()).
- The result of string.scan() is -1 if the string "AAA" wasn't part of the lower-case version of `&parameters`
- So variable `&AAA` gets set to 1, if a lower-case version of `&parameters` contain the string "AAA" (which is never the case since "AAA" is upper-case).

Maybe the writer of the script wanted to use string.upr() instead of string.lwr().

Comment: Hi Holger, thanks for your detailed answer. Just got two more questions: 1. what's the meaning of the 0 inside string.scan function? 2. why we compare the result of string.scan with -1?   Thanks!!

Comment: Goto http://www.lauterbach.com/manual.html and download ide_func.pdf and general_func.pdf. There you find a detailed explanation to the functions  (Your function STRing.SCAN() is in ide_func.pdf). For understanding the script language itself I recommend   training_practice.pdf